# Pandas groupby count with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

#### Example Data

Given the following data frame:

```
| feature | gene  |  target  | pos | 
| 1_1_1   | NRAS  |  AATTGG  | 60  |
| 1_1_1   | NRAS  |  TTGGCC  | 6   |
| 1_1_1   | NRAS  |  AATTGG  | 20  |
| 1_1_1   | KRAS  |  GGGGTT  |  0  |
| 1_1_1   | KRAS  |  GGGGTT  |  0  |
| 1_1_1   | KRAS  |  GGGGTT  |  0  |
| 1_1_2   | NRAS  |  CCTTAA  | 2   |
| 1_1_2   | NRAS  |  GGAATT  | 8   |
| 1_1_2   | NRAS  |  AATTGG  | 60  |
```

#### The problem

For each feature, I would like to count how many targets appear in each gene, with the following rules:

- If a target appears in only one position (pos column) for each gene, it gets a count of 1 for every time seen
- If the same target appears in multiple positions for each gene, it gets a count of (count at position/total positions found)
- Summarize total counts of each gene per feature

#### What I've done so far

```
matches.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene"]).size().reset_index()

matches['multi_mapped'] = np.where(matches.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene", "target"]).pos.transform('nunique') > 1, "T", '')
```

Which gives me a dataframe where targets that appear at more than one position are flagged as true. Now I just need to figure out how to normalize the counts.

#### Desired output

```
| feature | gene  |  count
| 1_1_1   | NRAS  |   2
| 1_1_1   | KRAS  |   1
| 1_1_2   | NRAS  |   3
```

So in the example above for 1_1_1 NRAS, where AATTGG is found at both position 60 and position 20, each would get a count of .5. Since TTGGCC was found once at one position, so it gets a count of 1. This makes a total count of 2.

If for 1_1_1 NRAS TTGGCC was found 3 times at the same position, each of those would get a count of 1, for a total of 3 + .5 + .5 = 4.

The solution needs to check for the same target appearing at different positions and then adjust the counts accordingly, and that is the part I'm having a difficult time with. My ultimate goal is to choose the gene with the highest count per group.

Comment: I see, can you explain why NRAS is 3 ?

Comment: Can you explain the `count at position/total positions found` a little better? If `| 1_1_1   | NRAS  |  AATTGG  | 20  |` were repeated so that `1_1_1 | NRAS` had 4 total entries what would the count be? 2.5?

Comment: You could call `nunique()` instead of `size()` in your `groupby`, however I believe this would bug out in a situation like @ALollz describes.

Comment: try `df.groupby(["feature", "gene", "target"]).nunique().groupby(level=[0,1]).feature.agg(sum)`

Comment: So in the example, where AATTGG is found at both position 60 and position 20, each would get a count of .5, TTGGCC was found once at one position, so it gets a count of 1. For a total count of 2. If TTGGCC was found 3 times at the same position, each of those would get a count of 1, for a total of 3.

None of the suggestions are addressing the need to check for the same target appearing at different positions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Question if TTGGCC in your data frame as a value of 6 in pos column, why is this considered position 1?

Comment: A value of 6 in the pos column indicates that the sequence starts at index six in comparison to a longer sequence. This does not indicate the number of occurrences, which is indicated in a column called "count".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. If there is a more efficient way to to do this, I'm all ears!

```
    # flag targets that are multi-mapped and add flag as new column
    matches['multi_mapped'] = np.where(matches.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene", "target"]).pos.transform('nunique') > 1, "T", '')

    # separate multi and non multi mapped reads using flag
    non = matches[matches["multi_mapped"] != "T"]\
        .drop("multi_mapped", axis=1)
    multi = matches[matches["multi_mapped"] == "T"]\
        .drop("multi_mapped", axis=1)

    # add counts to non multi mapped reads
    non = non.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene", "target"])\
        .count().reset_index().rename(columns={"pos":"count"})

    # add counts to multi-mapped reads with normaliztion 
    multi["count"] = multi.groupby(["FeatureID", "gene", "target"])\
          .transform(lambda x: 1/x.count())
    multi.drop("pos", axis=1, inplace=True)

    # join the multi and non back together
    counts = pd.concat([multi, non], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me why the count on first row should be 2. Could you try to play around this:

```
import pandas as pd
feature = ["1_1_1"]*6 +["1_1_2"]*3
gene = ["NRAS"]*3+["KRAS"]*3+["NRAS"]*3
target = ["AATTGG","TTGGCC", "AATTGG"]+ ["GGGGTT"]*3 + ["CCTTAA", "GGGGTT", "AATTGG"]
pos = [60,6,20,0,0,0,2,8,60]
df = pd.DataFrame({"feature":feature,
                   "gene":gene,
                   "target":target,
                   "pos":pos})

df.groupby(["feature", "gene"])\
  .apply(lambda x:len(x.drop_duplicates(["target", "pos"])))
```

Comment: So in the example, where AATTGG is found at both position 60 and position 20, each would get a count of .5, TTGGCC was found once at one position, so it gets a count of 1. For a total count of 2. 

If TTGGCC was found 3 times at the same position, each of those would get a count of 1, for a total of 3.